# How to operate on unsaved Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, matlab, abaqus

I'd like to automate a loop:

1. ABAQUS generates a Excel file;
2. Matlab utilises data in Excel file;
3. loop 1 and 2.

Now my question is: after step 1, the Excel file from ABAQUS is unsaved as Book1. I cannot use Matlab command to save it. Is there a way not to save this ''Book1'' file, but use the data in it? Or if I can find where it is so I can use the data inside? (I assume that Excel always saves the file even though user doesn't?)

Thank you!

Comment: Clarify how ABAQUS generates an Excel file.  Is this an abaqus python script or something?  Also why use excel format?  If you are not actually using the microsoft excel application, don't use their proprietary format.

Comment: I don't actually think it could work, you are better off just to stream your data to both the excel (for whatever reason) and to Matlab (for processing). I think it would be incredibly inefficient to stream to excel, save to excel file, load to matlab, process data, save.

Comment: If you're on a Windows machine you can utilize the ActiveX Interface to control Excel directly from MATLAB. See [this MATLAB Central post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94822-are-there-any-examples-that-show-how-to-use-the-activex-automation-interface-to-connect-matlab-to-ex) for an example. Whether or not it's the most efficient method is a different question.

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for the replies! I'm looping ABAQUS by coding in MATLAB. My idea is modifying parameters in ABAQUS python script, and loop this operation, to get some output and utilise these output in MATLAB again. I'm choosing to get Excel output simply because it is readable. The other way is to get an ABAQUS.rpt file instead of Excel, which is quite messy and unreadable.

Comment: Is there a way to stream data from ABAQUS directly into MATLAB? I thought there are only two ways: excel or rpt.

Comment: I'm trying ActiveX, see if there's any luck.

Comment: Abaqus python is python. You can write to any file format you like.  To my knowledge Abaqus does not directly support excel, so id assume you are already using some python module for that. You might just as well use csv for example.

Comment: Oh now I get it - I suppose you are using the excel plug-in which pipes the data right to the excel application, leaving you in unsaved file limbo.  (Sorry I didn't know about that plug-in).

Answer (score 0):

As agentp mentioned, if you are running Abaqus via a Python script, you can just use Python to create a .txt file to save all the relevant information. If well structured, a .txt file can be as readable as an Excel spreadsheet. Because Matlab and Python have intrinsic functions to read and write files this communication can be easily done.

As for Matlab calling Abaqus, you can use something similar to:

```
system('abaqus cae nogui=YOUR_SCRIPT.py')
```

Comment: Thanks to you both!  @agentp As far as I understand, in order to edit this Python file which generated by ABAQUS, I have to follow some 'ABAQUS' syntax to make it work, rather than just Python syntax. I'm not very familiar with these. So I gave up and use Abaqus report files instead, which is messy but usable.

Answer (score 0):

Your script that pipes to Excel should have some code similar to this:

```
 abq_ExcelUtilities.excelUtilities.XYtoExcel(
       xyDataNames='S:Mises PI: PART-1-1 E: 4309 IP: 1', trueName='')
```

writing the same data to a report (.rpt) file the code looks like this:

```
 x0 = session.xyDataObjects['S:Mises PI: PART-1-1 E: 4309 IP: 1']
 session.writeXYReport(fileName='abaqus.rpt', xyData=(x0, ))
```

now to "roll your own", use that `x0` object: `x0.data` is a regular python tuple holding the actual data which you can write to a file however you like, eg:

```
 file=open('myfile.csv','w')
 for point in x0.data: file.write('%g,%g\n'%point)
 file.close()
```

(you can comment or delete the `writeXYReport` call )